# error running git push heroku master

Tags: heroku

I just set up my heroku account. 
I am in my app's root directory..

so I run

```bash
heroku login
## give my credentials
heroku create --stack cedar
heroku keys:add
git push heroku master
```

then I get the error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname heroku: Name or service not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the Heroku git remote address is somehow broken.

You could first try to access Heroku directly by performing `host heroku.com` and `ssh git@heroku.com -T` and see what that yields. Like this: [Getting error while trying to push to Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366445/getting-error-while-trying-to-push-to-heroku)

With `host heroku.com` you should get something like:

```
$ host heroku.com
heroku.com has address 50.19.85.132
heroku.com has address 50.19.85.154
heroku.com has address 50.19.85.156
heroku.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
heroku.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
heroku.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
heroku.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
heroku.com mail is handled by 10 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
heroku.com mail is handled by 10 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
heroku.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Then try fixing your .git/config file, with:

```
git@heroku.com:your_app.git
```

Like this: [Can't push to existing live heroku app on Cedar Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782079/cant-push-to-existing-live-heroku-app-on-cedar-stack)

If those two don't help, then could be something more complex.